# Combine first two entries in each column as the header when reading excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've been searching this for a while but still can't figure it out. I appreciate if you can provide me some help.

I have an excel file:

```
      ,   John,    James,    Joan,
      ,   Smith,   Smith,    Smith,
Index1,   234,     432,      324,
Index2,   2987,    234,      4354,
```

I'd like to read it into a dataframe, such that 
"John Smith,   James Smith,    Joan Smith" is my header.
I've tried the follwoing, but my header is still "John, James, Joan"

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(myfile, header=None)
row = df.apply(lambda x: str(x.iloc[0]) + str(x.iloc[1]))
df.append(row,ignore_index=True)

nrow = df.shape[0]
df = pd.concat([df.ix[nrow:], df.ix[2:nrow-1]])
```

Comment: is it csv or xls file?

Comment: It's an xls file, thanks

Answer (score 1):

May be it's easier to do by hand?:

```
>>> import itertools

>>> xl = pd.ExcelFile(myfile, header=None)
>>> sh = xl.book.sheet_by_index(0)
>>> rows = (sh.row_values(i) for i in xrange(sh.nrows))
>>> hd = zip(*itertools.islice(rows, 2))[1:]   # read first two rows
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(rows)                    # create DataFrame from remaining rows
>>> df = df.set_index(0)
>>> df.columns = [' '.join(x) for x in hd]     # rename columns
>>> df
        John Smith  James Smith  Joan Smith
0                                          
Index1         234          432         324
Index2        2987          234        4354
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the two levels separate if you want. This might be useful if you want to filter columns based on last name alone, for instance. Otherwise, the other solution(s) certainly work better than this seems to.

Normally this works for me:

```
In [103]: txt = '''John,James,Joan
     ...: Smith,Smith,Smith
     ...: 234,432,324
     ...: 2987,234,4354
     ...: '''

In [104]: x = pandas.read_csv(StringIO(txt), header=[0,1])
     ...: x.columns = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(x.columns.tolist())
     ...: x
     ...:
```

But for some reason, that's missing the first row :/

```
In [105]: x
Out[105]: 
    John  James   Joan
   Smith  Smith  Smith
0   2987    234   4354
```

I'll check in with the pandas mailing list to see if that's a bug.

Comment: This works perfectly for me when reading my files in from csv.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around by converting the Excel file to csv file and the followings:

```
df = pd.read_csv(myfile, header=None)    
header = df.apply(lambda x: str(x.ix[0]) + ' ' + str(x.ix[1]))
df = df[2:]
df.columns = header
```

Here's the output:

```
Out[252]: 
  John Smith  James Smith  Joan Smith
2        234          432         324
3       3453         2342         563
```

However when I read in by pd.ExcelFile (and parse the specific sheet I'm interested in), there is a similar issue as @Paul H had. It seems Excel format considers the first row as column names by default and returns me sth like:

```
   Smith 234    Smith 432   Smith 324
3       3453         2342         563
```